# Adding DNS to Console brings "A Security package Specific Error Occured"

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2019

I am trying to add the DNS server of my child domain DC to a console on my local machine. The machine is parent domain joined and on a network connecting the parent and child DCs. I am logged in as an Enterprise Admin. When I add the server to my DNS console I get the error:

```
A security package specific error occurred.
Would you like to add it anyway?
```

There are trust relationships between the child and the parent domains so I don't see what the error is. I don't have anything in my event log on this problem. I also can't access the child domain with my Group Policy editor either. What does this error mean and how do I regain access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed this issue. On the child domains I went into the DNS server and clicked on Properties and under Interfaces and under Listen on I checked the box for the LAN address that shares the same network with my computer.

If I uncheck that box I get the Security package error.